# convert string representation of a object using python

Tags: python

I am having string `PyObject [methodCall=1001, attributeName=javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.request.charset, attributeValue=UTF-8]`

and in python I am having class :

```
class PyObject:
def __init__(self, methodCall, attributeName, attributeValue):
    self.methodCall = methodCall
    self.attributeName = attributeName
    self.attributeValue = attributeValue
```

I am receiving above string from socket I want to convert that received string to object of `PyObject` so that I can access attributes like `pyobj.methodCall`.

I have tried with `json.loads()` but its giving me `dict`.

Comment: What have you tried? This is straightforward with regex.

Comment: For example, a very rough regex would be `r'methodCall=(?P<methodCall>.*?)attributeName=(?P<attributeName>.*?)attributeValue=(?P<attributeValue>.*)\]'` See https://regex101.com/r/suW51k/1

Comment: @DeepSpace sorry forgot to add, I have tried with `json.loads()` but its giving `dict` object

Comment: The input string is not in JSON format.

Comment: @DeepSpace actually input string handled by different system, so I can't modify that one. regex is the only one option?

Comment: It's the only *easy* way, yeah. See https://regex101.com/r/suW51k/1

Comment: @DeepSpace , Actually I am looking for a generic way so that if in case any new attribute gets added to input string then I don't have to modify regex. Only adding attribute in python object should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the requirement for this to be dynamic in the comments (you should add it to the question as well) consider this solution.

It is not the most beautiful or elegant, but it gets the job done.

This solution abuses the ability to dynamically create classes and instances with [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#type).

```
string = 'PyObject [methodCall=1001, attributeName=javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.request.charset, attributeValue=UTF-8]'

class_name, string = string.split(' ', maxsplit=1)

data = [substring.strip() for substring in string.replace('[', '') \
                                       .replace(']', '').split(',') if substring]

print(data)
# ['methodCall=1001', 'attributeName=javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.request.charset',
#  'attributeValue=UTF-8']

data_dict = {}
for d in data:
    key, value = d.split('=')
    data_dict[key] = value

print(data_dict)
#  {'attributeValue': 'UTF-8',
#   'attributeName': 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.request.charset', 'methodCall': '1001'}

def init(self, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)

obj = type(class_name, (), {'__init__': init})(**data_dict)
print(obj)
# <__main__.PyObject object at 0x00520C70>
print(obj.methodCall)
# 1001
print(obj.attributeName)
# javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.request.charset
```